# Multi-user test approach for wicket application

Tags: java, testing, wicket, integration-testing, multi-user

We are developing a Wicket Application where users can log in and perform searches on a Lucene index. They can also modify their own, small index.

We have great test coverage for single-user scenarios. However, as the application is intended to be run on a server and have multiple, concurrent users, I would like to be able to set-up a test that covers this scenario (e.g. 1 application, 10 concurrent users).

I have some experience using `jmeter`, but I would prefer a `WicketTester`-style approach if possible.

Does anyone have expercience setting up such a test? Or good pointers?

Comment: TestNG can do parallel tests fairly painlessly. But the fundamental problem with parallel tests is that they aren't repeatable. Which is fine for load testing, not so for your unit and integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

We also use Wicket but concurrent users is not my main focus (no end-users). Sometimes I need to check cookie-behaviour, session-management etc. and then I use [SAHI](http://sahipro.com/) which also exists as open source IMO and as a demo. We use the Pro version also in other projects. From my perspective easy to learn and to handle.

```
_navigateTo("http://myapp/login.html");
// login as first user
...
// launch a new browser instance
var $instanceId = _launchNewBrowser("http://myapp/login.html");
_wait(5000);
// wait and select the new browser instance using the instanceId
_selectBrowser($instanceId);
// log in as second user
// send a chat message to first user
...

// Select the base window
_selectBrowser();
// view chat window and verify second user's chat message has arrived
...
```

Taken from [documentation](http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/multiple-browsers.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple browser instances are a Sahi Pro feature and are not included in the open source version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it won't be possible to do what you need with WicketTester.

It starts one instance of the application. This is fine!
But it also acts like a browser, i.e. a single client.
I have used http://databene.org/contiperf for some perf tests (non-Wicket) before and I liked it. But if you try to use it with WicketTester then you either will have to have a separate WicketTester for each user or you will face synchronization issues in WicketTester itself.

I'd recommend you to use JMeter or Gatling. A user from the community made this integration: https://github.com/vanillasource/wicket-gatling. I haven't used it yet but I hope to try it soon.